# Why would a utility designed for file management work out of alphabetical order?

Tags: conversion, sorting, organizer-software

In an isolated environment, I am using an .EML to .MSG file converter, [ReliefJet Essentials](https://www.reliefjet.com/Essentials/Features/OutlookConvertEML2MSG), to convert a large repository of files (in the hundreds of thousands), keeping directory structure intact - which starts with folders for each letter, and goes deeper from there.

The conversion software doesn't give a log of every file completed (thankfully) but does keep an error log of everything that fails, which gives me some indication of the route it takes.

The thing that confuses me is not taking the folders in alphabetical order. The error log reports that the folders were converted in the order:

`D, N, P, C, I, S, M, G, T, V, B, O, E, Q, A, U, R, F, L`

Even subfolders when they appear in this list were attended out of order. For example, under `B`, folders were attended (truncated for privacy):

`BLA, BD, BRE, BAL, BRA, BEL, BLU`

I corrected some problematic files and ran the conversion request again, skipping existing files. The log returned any errors in the exact same order, which makes me think this is not a 'random pick' but a set order.

What I'm wondering is how this order is reached.
It doesn't appear to be based on folder size or number of files, as with both values:

- `N` is smaller than `D`
- `L` is about the same size as `D`
- `P` is bigger than `N`, `D` and `L` combined

Is there any sort method that would explain why the utility picks folders in this non-alphabetical order, which appears haphazard but is repeatable and reproducible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is probably the order that files and folders were found on the disk.

Let's say you create a folder on the disk

- Folder J

Then, some time later, you create another folder

- Folder J
- Folder B

Yes `Folder B` is alphabetically before J, but is was created after.

A directory list is just that, a list of the things in the directory, and it is much simpler to append items to that list than it is to read the entire list, sort it by some arbitrary algorithm and then write the list back to disk.

In terms of adding items to that directory it would be very slow to add items to that directory if you sorted it every time, in fact you could cripple a machine by doing the simple act of adding a ton of zero byte files to a directory, even if the filename were sequential it would have to check by sorting them each time.

Even renaming a file in a large directory could be painfully slow as it would trigger a sort operation on the folder.

So instead an item is simply appended to the list each time. No sorting, no nothing. Just an append and close.

If you want a sorted list then you can scan the directory and sort your own list. Over the lifetime of that directory it may have been faster for programs for it to already be sorted, but that problem is minor compared to the performance hit taken by doing it every time a file is written or renamed.

So what you are probably seeing is the order that directories or files were added to your directory instead of a sorted list.

Your program doesn't care about "file management". All it cares about is the content of those files and making sure it runs through the list.

It is haphazard, but at the same time it is repeatable because that is the order that the names are written to the folder list.

It *looks* random but it really isn't.